# What's the best practice to expose ENV vars in a React JS app deployed on K8S?

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-pod

I have a question regarding what are the best practices in managing environment variables for a React application deployed on K8S, like third-party service apiKeys from example.

Usually one could put environment variables inside the `.env` files, so to be picked during build phase, local or production. But we don't want to do the same while building Docker images as it would generate "hardwired" images, while the consensus/best-practice dictates that we should strictly separate code from configuration.

Containers should be agnostic to the environment in which they are to be deployed, after all.

To make thing works we wrote a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script where we take variables from the environment the container is run into, and we write those variables values into the `window` object, so that React runtime can access them.

To be more clear, this is the content of our `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
if [ -v VARIABLE_NAME ]; then
    variable_name="window.VARIABLE_NAME = '${VARIABLE_NAME}';"
fi

echo "${variable_name}" > /usr/share/nginx/html/static/app-config.js

exec "$@"
```

And in the `<head>` section of our React's `index.html` we have this:

`<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/static/app-config.js"></script>`

So all the variables are accessible via `window.VARIABLE_NAME`.

In our case we're taking env variables exposed into Pod by Kubernetes.
Our solution works, but we need to understand if there are better approaches.

These are useful links we followed:
https://12factor.net/config
https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/#what-does-docker-technology-add-to-just-plain-lxc

Comment: If sensitive vars are in app-config.js and are reaching the browser, they are exposed and can be easily retrieved, unless you are sending them encrypted and only the server has the key. Never ever send sensitive info base64 encoded. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm editing the question, since "sensitive" is not the right word in this case. We're refering to exposable values, such as the Sentry's DSN or the reCAPTCHA publishable key, nothing that must be kept private

Answer (score 0):

you can store the key:value pairs of your ENVs in kubernetes secrets and expose them to your service as ENVs by referencing the secret(s) in your deployment.

secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  env1: value1
  env2: value2
```

deployment.yaml:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      containers:
        - name: <app>
          image: <image>
          env:
            - name: env1
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysecret
                  key: env1
            - name: env2
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysecret
                  key: env2
          ...
```

reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is perfectly clear, and in fact is exactly what we are doing. My doubts are about the next step: once we have the pod that is exposing the values, is there a more efficient way (compared to mine) to get those values within the React app?

Comment: ah okay, now i got it. thought i could help you out with some k8s examples, but i don't know much about react apps. i found this link after a quick google search - does this provide you a solution for your problem? https://dev.to/akdevcraft/react-runtime-variables-49dc

Answer (score 0):

[ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) is what you are looking for to achieve it.

> A ConfigMap is an API object used to store non-confidential data in key-value pairs. Pods can consume ConfigMaps as environment variables, command-line arguments, or as configuration files in a volume.
> A ConfigMap allows you to decouple environment-specific configuration from your container images, so that your applications are easily portable.

In short way `ConfigMap` takes variables from file and attach them to Pod.

You can get familiar in more details in another [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70895207/17126151). I wrote step by step with explanation in each step.

If you have sensitive data you can read about [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

> A Secret is an object that contains a small amount of sensitive data such as a password, a token, or a key. Such information might otherwise be put in a Pod specification or in a container image Using a Secret means that you don't need to include confidential data in your application code.

Comment: Hello RadekW. I knew ConfigMaps and your explanation was really nice, so thank you :)
However my question is different, I'm sorry: my doubts were NOT about how to expose values from a Pod, BUT instead how to get those values in a React application that lives inside that pod at runtime, and if the methods I used was to be considered best practice or not. Hope this clarifies :)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55962511/10347794) is a good answer which explains everything and yes, you are doing it fine. Other people do the same. Let me know if this is helpful for you